# Get category ids by page layout name

Tags: layout, category

I have a little problem, I don't know how to solve it. My problem is I want get category id by the page layout selection. For example from admin I have created new layout 'category-like'. just like other layouts, 1-colomn, 2-colomns-with-left-bar .. So now I want get which categories are used this layout. If two categories are used this layout mens, then I need that category id ...Please help me guys..

**Update:**

At least please tell me, how get **page layout** name from category id ...

Answer (score 2):

> list.phtml

Get the layout of Current Category

```
$yourCatId = $this->getCategoryId(); 
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate($yourCatId);
```

This is to get list of all category and there layouts:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('id')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
->addAttributeToSelect('url')
->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');

foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    if ($category->getIsActive()) { // Only pull Active categories
        $entity_id = $category->getId();
        echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate($entity_id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for for answer, But I want get that id from outside, not in list.phtml file...

Comment: I have update the code a bit, this will give you all categories with there layouts, hope this is what you want

Comment: You can get the current category in any view, block, model or controller file, by calling `Mage::registry('current_category');`

Comment: @alex.ayg I guess, This works only for product view page

Comment: @TBIInfotech this works when category or product controller actions are called (i.e. category view, product view)
`http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php` `_initCategory()` method

Comment: Thanks again, I think we are almost close. I ll use this code in a custom module. This working only in category page only..

Comment: OK, please verify if the answer worked